# Saying Borchu Second Time Ma'ariv Nusach Ashkenaz

Tags: tefilla, maariv, nusach-ashkenaz, arriving-late

In a Nusach Ashkenaz minyan/shul, there are certain individuals who (not infrequently) arrive late for Ma'ariv, and therefore miss Borchu at the beginning.  Certain of these people have some kind of background in Nusach Sefarad.  Therefore at the end of Ma'ariv they say Borchu again on their own initiative.

The **main** question is: Is this appropriate from the perspective of the halacha/minhag of Nusach Ashkenaz?

As a **secondary** question: Also, when those same individuals arrive late for Shacharit and miss Borchu there (including on Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Friday), they never repeat Borchu then.  As far as I know Nusach Sefarad does not have a second Borchu in Shacharit, so what is the justification for saying a second Borchu aloud at Ma'ariv and not Shacharit?

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Did you mean "Nusach Sefarad has a second Borchu in Shacharit"?

Answer (score 2):

Nusach Sfard, Eidot Hamizrach, and also the Israeli Nusach Ashkenaz include a second *barchu* both at Shacharit and Maariv.

In Nusach Sfard (and Eidot Hamizrach), it is said after the kaddish right before Aleinu. In Nusach Ashkenaz it is said at the very end of davening, after the final kaddish.

Source: i've gone to shuls of all 3 nuschaot.

As for why no *barchu* at the end of Shacharit, i don't know. It seems inconsistent to me, and might be wrong too.

Comment: Supplement and related to this, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/missing-barchu-at-maariv

Comment: There are batei knesset that daven nusach Sfarad that do not say the second Barechu after Shacharit on days with Kriyat haTorah, since the olim leTorah said Barechu, but do on other days.

Comment: In Eretz Yisroel borchu is said after shacharis, except for Monday and Thursday