# Missing " Borechu " by Maariv

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, maariv

If one misses ברכו at מעריב , should he rush his שמונה עשרה in order to say it after *Davening* ?

Comment: Not all authorities accept Borchu b'asra, so one should ask the gabbai of the minyan if the minhog hamokaum is to do so [note to self: refrain from typing in Ashkenazis]

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3679

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Barchu at Maariv](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/missing-barchu-at-maariv)

Comment: @DannySchoemann "should he rush his שמונה עשרה" is not part of the other question. This question seems to presume an affirmative answer to the other question and move on from there. It would be a great deal more valuable if it would refer to material in the answers to the other question first, explicitly, but I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

most certainly not. it would be no different than rushing you meeting with a dignitary in order to pay him respect as he leaves...
we never find that one should rush his davening for any mitzva, and barachu is no different.

Comment: A source would enhance the quality of this answer.